# Add Wireless password without connecting

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

Is there a way in Windows 10 to add a password for a wireless network without having the wireless network available?

I need to setup a laptop for a colleague and know the wireless details for the office he's in but I don't have that wireless network where I am.

I would like to tell windows what the SSID and password is without having to drive over to the other office just to input the password.

Is this possible? Are the passwords stored in the registry somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find bunch of XML file in this directory.
"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>Your_SSID</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <hex>XXXXX</hex>
            <name>Your_SSID</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>manual</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>true</protected>
                <keyMaterial>XXXXX</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
    <MacRandomization xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v3">
        <enableRandomization>false</enableRandomization>
    </MacRandomization>
</WLANProfile>
```

Make a new file then input necessary data in required fields.

Comment: How do I determine the file name? It looks to be a GUID

Comment: There is a Online GUID Generator in following url "https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx"

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can definitely do this.  Goto Control Panel -> Click on Network and Sharing Center -> On the left menu, click on Change adapter settings -> right click on your wireless adapter -> click on connect/disconnect -> click on Manage known networks -> click on add a new network.  Select your options, save and that's it.

If you open a dos/cmd windows, you'll be able to type the following command and get the entire wireless profile (password included) in xml format.

```
netsh wlan export profile name="WifiNetwork" folder="C:\path\" key=clear
```

Ensure that the profile name reflects the profile name configured on your machine.